# swi-prolog can't include external file?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Lets say I have a file `main.pl` with the following content

```
/* I tried these one at a time, not all at once... */
[externalFile].
['externalFile'].
['externalFile.pl'].
['./externalFile.pl']./*this was an answer to a similar SO question*/
consult(externalFile).
/*... etc ...*/
```

now lets use it...

```
$ swipl -l externalFile.pl
/* 12 second loading delay */
/* everything works perfect! */
$ swipl -l main.pl
/* 0 second loading delay */
/* let's try anything from externalFile... */
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: [...]
/* main.pl might as well be empty */
?- consult(externalFile).
/* 0 second loading delay */
true.
/* true? oh my bad! Lets try again... */
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: [...]
?- [externalFile].
/* 12 second loading delay... seems better... */
true.
/* been lied to before... */
/* and yet every thing works perfect now! */
```

note: `consult(externalFile).` only has no effect when `consult(externalFile).` is in `main.pl`.  Otherwise, `consult(externalFile).` does succeed in importing the file while in a terminal session.

So how do I write source code without resorting to having to copy and paste my whole program into the terminal (or just have all my program source code have a file size of 15+ MEGA bytes worth of manual inclusions!) if the terminal is the only place where import commands will work?

---

note: I have also checked the line separator encoding (dos vs windows) (this was the answer to another question)

note: independent clauses defined directly within main.pl work fine

Comment: See: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse52

Comment: You should look at the Prolog documentation. `[]` in this context is same as  `consult()`. These are directives. Directives require `:-`. So, for example, `:- [externalFile].` or `:- consult(externalFile).`.

Comment: @lurker why not writing as an answer, seems complete enough and very helpful :) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operations such as `consult` are referred to in Prolog as *directives*. Prolog *directives* are recognized by Prolog differently depending upon whether you are using the interactive environment, or you are executing a directive from a Prolog source file.

In the interactive environment, a directive is just typed in at the `?-` prompt:

```
?- consult('myfile').
```

When you consult a file, Prolog sees the file as a series of assertions of facts and rules. However, if Prolog sees the `:-` operator, it treats the line as a directive in the file. So from a file, you must use that operator:

```
:- consult('myfile').
```

The brackets `[]` are sort of a short hand for `consult()`. You are giving Prolog a list of files to consult. The above would be equivalent to:

```
?- [myfile].
```

And

```
:- [myfile].
```

There are also different forms that are acceptable. A `consult` argument must be an atom. If you have a file called `myfile.pl`, it can be consulted as:

```
:- [myfile].
:- ['myfile'].
:- ['myfile.pl'].
```

And similarly:

```
:- consult(myfile).
:- consult('myfile').
:- consult('myfile.pl').
```

`consult(myfile.pl)` or `[myfile.pl]` will result in an error since the, without the quotes, `myfile.pl` will not be seen as a single atom.

The list (`[]`) form of consult will accept multiple files:

```
:- [myfile, anotherfile].
```

---

To address your comment:

> `consult(externalFile).` only has no effect when
>   `consult(externalFile).` is in `main.pl`.

When you put `consult(externalFile).` on a line by itself in a file (like `main.pl`) that you consult, you are telling Prolog that you wish to assert the term (fact in this case), `consult(externalFile)` which consists of the functor `consult` and has one atomic argument, `externalFile`. So it actually *did* do something, just not what you were expecting.